# rpm/yum: require minimum version of optional package

Tags: yum, rpm

I have two packages, `python-modules` and `python-modules-foo`. `python-modules-foo` does not require `python-modules` to be installed, but if `python-modules` *is* installed, it must be at least version X. In this scenario, a Python module `foo` is part of `python-modules` prior to version X; I then moved `foo` to its own package and removed it from `python-modules` as of version X.

Currently, I have `Conflicts: python-modules < X` in the spec file for `python-modules-foo`, which prevents `python-modules-foo` from being installed unless `python-modules` version X is already installed. Is there a way to configure the packages and/or yum so that  `yum install python-modules-foo` will upgrade `python-modules` if necessary, but does not install otherwise?

I realize I can simply attempt to install `python-modules-foo` and, if it fails, repeat after upgrading `python-modules` myself. I am just curious if `yum` can handle this type of optional dependency on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
    Conflicts: python-modules < X
add
    Requires: python-modules >= X
if you want assistance from yum during upgrade.

Yum (and many rpm based depsolvers) doesn't automate Conflicts: handling.